# Adding Custom (domain+SSL) on google app engine which i bought from GoDaddy

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to add a custom domain with SSL in my google app engine project, according to the steps defined here [using-custom-domains-and-ssl](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl), i successfully added my domain but when i am trying to add the cert by going to `SSL Certificates` tap i am seeing a certificate which is already added, now can anyon eplease tell me, can i use this SSL certificate or will i have to add the cert manually by myself.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on several factors. You should verify the information in the existing certificate is correct before attempting to use it.

If this was a certificate you added previously AND it matches your domain name AND it is not expired, then yes you can continue to use it.

If any of the above is false, you should import your new certificate instead.